# How can I create a component with custom alignment procedure?

Tags: delphi

I want to create a component but I am not satisfied with the way Align works so I want to create my own property to reposition the component in a completely different way.
But I am not sure where to hook in with it- where should it be called?

Comment: How do you want it to behave?

Comment: Something similar to the real Align but I want the components to overlap.

Comment: Example here: http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/17340

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you. Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/17340) by Steve Trefethen, a former Borland developer, shows how to use `alCustom`.

Answer (score 2):

One fast Access would be to override SetBounds, to ensure it's call you wold have to set an Alignment other then alNone

```
type
  TMyButton=Class(Tbutton)
      procedure SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer); override;

  End;

//..............


procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  With TMyButton.Create(self) do
    begin
      Parent := self;
      Width := 200;
      top := 100;
      Height := 100;
      align := alCustom; // was alRight thanks to David Heffernan
    end;
end;


{ TMyButton }

procedure TMyButton.SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
begin
   if Assigned(parent)  then
      begin // .. just e.g.
        ALeft :=  Parent.Width - Width -100 ;
        ATop := 100;
        AHeight := Parent.Height - Atop - 100 ;
      end;
   inherited;

end;
```

Comment: That does not work too good. For example when Parent changes its size my component's SetBounds is not fired so it can't reposition itself.

Comment: Sizing ist the Problem in my invironment, but you are right, there is a problem on maxi/minimizing

Comment: I tried again, with Delphi XE, if setting AWith to and a defined alignment it's working fine. Without Alignment as e.g. alRight Setbounds won't be called as needed.

Comment: Setting AlRight makes some problems: my component's height is discarded so I have to store it somewhere else and bring this value back; the form things the components is on the right and is showing scrollbars sometimes. This sounds "hacky".

Comment: Your right, the problem is the Control is not aligning on its own it's aligned by it's parent. My first try was RequestAlign but it didn't work as desired. I'm on the search for a better solution, but it may last due to duty :-(